# Как происходит передача изображения по сети\комутатору?

Tags: c++, linux, c, сеть, cisco

Изучаю подробно работу компьютерных сетей и не могу понять несколько вещей. То есть понимаю что являет собой физический уровень, то есть это кабеля между собой которые передают сигналы имеющую способность кодироваться и , соответственно, декодироваться. но пытаюсь разобрать это детально, на макроскопическом уровне и нахожу много тупиковых моментов. К примеру как происходит преображение цельного изображения в ряд символьных байтов? то есть по идее изображение - это закраска пикселей, и логично что компьютер нужно информировать о цвете каждого пикселя. Но смотря на скорость работы интернета видно что алгоритмы там сверхбыстрые. Можете разжевать или подтолкнуть на нужные ресурсы? Хочу в этом разобраться, как оно все обустроено на низком уровне, что бы перейти на верхний. Спасибо!

Comment: Преобразование изображения в байты и обратно не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к сетям

Comment: ну вы же шлете эти картинки с помощью построенных кабелей, без них это не сделалось бы возможным

Comment: @andreymal разве нет?

Comment: По кабелям шлют байты. А какие именно байты и откуда они взялись — для сети это абсолютно безразлично

Comment: на примере изучать проще, то что сеть предназначена для того что бы сделать это возможным,это становится ясным

Comment: Интересно каким образом шлются байты, и каким образом сохраняется уникальность информации, то есть каким образом компьютер понимает о чем идет речь, как происходит сборка тех или иных вещей, когда речь идет о нулях и единицах.

Comment: Это как спрашивать у производителя велосипедов о том, как изготавливают пиццу, которую вам доставил курьер. Не стоит смешивать две не связанные вещи — пицца отдельно, велосипеды отдельно

Comment: @andreymal У Вас есть какая либо информация либо ресурсы что бы ответить на мои вопросы=закрыть мои потребности знаний в этой сфере? что можете расказать\посоветовать?

Comment: Человек должен знать всё! @andreymal

Comment: Речь шла о принципах работы, а не о привязке к конкретностям. Интересует именно это

Comment: Вы меня хотите спутать, я же хочу приобрести знания и понимание работы этой отрасли деятельности человечества

Comment: Вы спутали сами себя, связав две не связанные друг с другом отрасли. Вы выполнили «привязку к конкретности», начав рассуждать про изображения непонятно зачем. Из-за этого на ваш вопрос трудно ответить внятно, так как непонятно, что вы хотите-то

Comment: «каким образом компьютер понимает о чем идет речь» — на уровне сети читайте про Ethernet и MAC-адреса (канальный уровень), IP (сетевой уровень) и TCP/UDP (транспортный уровень). Только вот к изображениям это никакого отношения не имеет. Задача сети — передать байты, остальное уже не её проблемы

Comment: @andreymal видимо хочу изучить IT:)

Comment: «IT» — это 7 лет информатики в школе плюс 4-6 лет в профильном университете, в рамках вопроса на Stack Overflow вам даже «принципы работы» не расскажут, потому что слишком обширно

Comment: Спасибо, пойду искать профильную литературу.

Comment: @andreymal на большую часть вопросов тут есть ответ в википедии.

Comment: @eri ага, но вдумчивое чтение всех релевантных статей займёт несколько лет 

Comment: Почитайте про сетевые модели [OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сетевая_модель_OSI) и [TCP/IP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP) (это примерно про одно и то же, только немного разная группировка уровней). То что вы спрашиваете реализуется на разных уровнях сетевой модели. Советую начать с общего ознакомления, потом изучать конкретные интересующие уровни.

Comment: Меня к примеру интересует сам процесс передачи сигнала по кабелю, то есть если я шлю адресату письмо с содержимым "я дома", происходит соответственно само "кодирование" в 001010100101, открывается тсп-соединение, используется айпи протокол, определяется адресат, но как физические устройства понимают где конец и начало символа? передается символ по отдельности или же весь текст целиком? или берется байт длиною в 8 бит и анализируется? Есть конкретная пошаговая информация об этом с наглядными примерами? Что бы я мог представить себе, когда что-то делаю : вот сейчас открылось соединение, и тд

Comment: @PasQuda111, еще раз, читайте про сетевые модели. Потом про конкретные уровни. Вы сейчас вопрос про несколько уровней сетевых моделей задаете, тут придется целый трактат написать, чтобы это все рассказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

От низкого к верхнему переходить не стоит. Лучше от высокого к низкому. Многим айтишникам не важно как работает половина уровней потому как они работают только с интерфейсами.

На физическом уровне конечно очень интересно, но на L2 там сразу возникнут вопросы - а почему сделано именно так?

Comment: Где тогда искать ответов?

Comment: Ну я к примеру понимаю что ток это упорядоченное движение электронов, и их взаимодействие и позволяет нам описывать информацию и сообщать о её количестве, потому что если брать 0 это отсутствие тока, 1 - его наличие, то сообщения таким образом можно закодировать и декодировать. Но как устройство понимает где начало где конец?

Comment: не всегда электронов, ну ладно.... 0 - отсутствие тока 1 - наличие вот тут совсем не верно: 0 в сетях чаще это отсутствие тока, затем сразу присутствие, а единица это сначала присутствие - потом отсутствие (IEEE 802.3).

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: а как эта разница в напряжениях фиксируется? запрограммированой платой? можно посмотреть ее исходный код?

Comment: какой стандарт возьмем за пример? самый простой https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE-T - типичный манчестер без выпендрежа. вот тут я набыдлокодил приём кадра с парктроника расчитывая время между импульсами. кадр принят при ready=true https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/e97dbdcb6eef3dbe49971e0324295d0d

Comment: То есть , после анализа всех данных, мы уже можем получить представление информации в двоичной системе исчисления , произвести декодирование, и соответственно дойти до режима представления. Это если опускать множества деталей. В идеале, еще бы мне иметь возможность рассказать что происходит на каждом из уровне в более менее понятных подробностях :)

Comment: Спасибо, уже намного понятнее

Comment: Уровни абстрактны их даже нет смысла учить дальше третьего) все слоями. На одном уровне может быть несколько кодирований. Как труба в трубе) откройте wireshark посмотреть на байтики